# I got an error saying except exception as e

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
    print("Recognizing.....")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-in')
    print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again please")
        return "None"`enter code here
```

whenever I try to run this code. i got an error saying "invalid syntax " except exception as e

Comment: The ``except`` must be at the same level of indentation as the ``try`` to which it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

The except is tabbed into the try, while it should be on the same line.

Try this instead:

```
try:
    print("Recognizing.....")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    print(f"user said: {query}\n")

except Exception as e:
    print("Say that again please")
    return "None"`enter code here
```